# Is there a way to replace double letters with single in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a word, `mississippi`, and I want to replace the first `ss` with `s` so that the word is `misissippi`. Is this possible with regex?

I've gotten this far `var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/i, "");`

But that simply replaces the double with nothing. I want to replace with a single letter.

Comment: So you *want* the misspelled version?

Comment: No, he wants mi*s*pelled version. ;)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - well played

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a lookahead *(in this case the second s isn't matched but its presence is only tested)*

```
var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)/i, "");
```

or using the capture group and the backreference in the replacement string *(the replacement string is the capture group content)*:

```
var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/i, "$1");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[^\w\s]|` here actually? Wouldn't `/(\w)\1/i` be enough?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: perhaps he wants to remove all that is not a word character or a whitespace at the same time. Note that in this case adding a quantifier is better: `/[^\w\s]+|(.)(?=\1)/i`

Comment: Nope - just want to turn two `ss` into one `s`

Comment: @Shamoon: In this case `/([a-z])(?=\1)/i` or `/([a-z])\1/i` with `"$1"` as replacement should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the replace function with what you want to replace the match : 
`var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/i, "s");`